# Synastic errors - Vim, Stack, Haskell development

Tags: vim, ghc, cabal, syntastic, haskell-stack

I am using [stack](https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack) for my Haskell development and [Syntastic](https://github.com/scrooloose/syntastic) for my error checking when editing in `Vim`. I have not installed the `haskell-platform`, instead, I use a `stack build --install-ghc` to get my environment up and running using the supported `GHC`, `cabal` and `lts` packages.

Normally, I use a `cabal sandbox` and `syntastic` works well with this. I see when I do a `let g:syntastic_debug=3` in `Vim`, `syntastic` runs a `cabal configure` which checks if the project dependencies are installed and then goes ahead and does some `hlint`, `hdevtools` and `ghc-mod` magic to give me some warnings and/or error messages.

Now, here is my problem. Since my `cabal` setup (installed from `stack`) doesn't know about my dependencies installed at `.stack-work` or `.stack` (not sure), it complains that I am missing necessary packages and blows up when syntastic runs in my `Vim` instance.

Trying to run a `stack exec -- cabal configure` returns the following error:

> Use of GHC's environment variable GHC_PACKAGE_PATH is incompatible with Cabal. use the flag --package-db to specify a package database (it can be used multiple times).

I haven't found out how to pass the `--package-db` option with the correct database. Nothing seems to work there.

So, the quetion - will successfully running a `stack exec -- cabal configure`, avoiding the `GHC_PACKAGE_PATH` issue get me to a working setup? Can anyone give me some direction here?

Comment: Another thing to try: what happens if you start Vim with `stack exec -- vim MyModule.hs`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hdevtools works. See here: http://seanhess.github.io/2015/08/05/practical-haskell-editors.html

I'm planning on keeping that up to date as new tools come out (like stack-ide).

Comment: confirmed; effortlessly got [hdevtools for Vim](https://github.com/bitc/vim-hdevtools) working via the linked blog post. Looking forward to more tooling for Haskell, huzzah!

Comment: oops, there is always something - while running vim and global installed hdevtools in an existing project, I had to run ``stack exec --no-ghc-package-path -- vim`` in order to get things running smoothly.

Comment: That's strange. It works in macvim just fine without doing that. I just switched to neovim, I'll see if it's still working as expected.

Comment: It's definitely working for me without needing to stack vim via stack exec. I'm using nvim, and I just run `nvim` in my terminal and it works.

Answer (score 0):

[This blogpost](https://blog.jez.io/haskell-development-with-neovim/) gives a nice introduction as well. Things change quickly in the haskell world and `ghc-mod` seems to be working well with stack now. The setup from the post requires neovim though.

The setup from the post worked perfectly fine for me and found all dependencies within the current stack project.